# How to get the ShareName of a local drive in VBA?

Tags: vba, share

I am trying to get the ShareName of a local drive. Used the code below, but it looks like the code does not produce that. only the share name of the network drives

please see code below

```
Sub VBA_Get_SharedName()
Dim fs, fol, netpath
For i = 1 To 26
B$ = Chr(64 + i) + ":\"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fol = fs.getfolder(B$)
netpath = fol.drive.ShareName
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c7542ab5-c8be-4632-bcdf-d1b216d021b0